# OpenGL First Cube Render Not Working

Tags: c++, opengl

I have setup all the vertices and indices for my cube, my GLFW and GLEW inits perfectly every run and my shaders compile and run just fine. Whenever I try multiply my cube's vertices by a matrix parsed into the shader, I see nothing every time I run the app. I have tried both perspective and orthographic projections and nothing appears to work. Here are fragments of my code. glCall is also just a definition for debugging OpenGL Calls.

```
while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) 
{
    glClearColor(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glm::mat4 model = glm::mat4();
    glm::mat4 view = glm::translate(glm::mat4(), glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, -3.0f));
    //glm::mat4 proj = glm::ortho(-8.0f, 8.0f, -6.0f, 6.0f);
    glm::mat4 proj = glm::perspective(glm::radians(45.0f), 800.0f/600.0f, 1.0f, 100.0f);
    glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(shader, "proj"), 1, GL_FALSE, &proj[0][0]);
    glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(shader, "view"), 1, GL_FALSE, &view[0][0]);
    glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(shader, "model"), 1, GL_FALSE, &model[0][0]);

    glCall(glUseProgram(shader));
    glCall(glBindVertexArray(cube.VAO));
    glCall(glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, cube.IBO));
    glCall(glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, cube.indexCount, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0));

    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    glfwPollEvents();
}
```

Here is my shader code aswell:

```
#SHADER vertex
#version 430 

layout(location = 0) in vec3 position;

uniform mat4 model;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 proj;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = proj * view * model * vec4(position, 1.0f);
}

#SHADER fragment
#version 430 

layout(location = 0) out vec4 color;
uniform vec4 colour;

void main()
{
    color = vec4(vec3(1.0, 0.5, 0.31) * vec3(1.0, 1.0, 1.0), 1.0);
}
```

And these are the cube vetices and indices i utilize if they are needed:

```
GLfloat vertices[24] = {
    // front
    -1.0, -1.0,  1.0,
    1.0, -1.0,  1.0,
    1.0,  1.0,  1.0,
    -1.0,  1.0,  1.0,
    // back
    -1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
    1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
    1.0,  1.0, -1.0,
    -1.0,  1.0, -1.0
};
GLint indices[36] = {
    // front
    0, 1, 2,
    2, 3, 0,
    // top
    1, 5, 6,
    6, 2, 1,
    // back
    7, 6, 5,
    5, 4, 7,
    // bottom
    4, 0, 3,
    3, 7, 4,
    // left
    4, 5, 1,
    1, 0, 4,
    // right
    3, 2, 6,
    6, 7, 3
};
```

I always get nothing displaying on the screen except for if I only multiply the position in my shader by only the orthogonal projection matrix and nothing else. I have set the ViewPort and Enabled Depth Buffering, but nothing else. Is there anything else I need to enable or disable or modify, because I'm confused as to why nothing will render in the cull of my projection.

Comment: At a glance, is the cube _actually_ within the view of the camera? :) If you translate -3 into the Z axis and the cube is from -1 to 1, and you're "looking" the wrong way, you shouldn't be able to see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`glUniform*`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glUniform.xhtml) specify the value of a uniform variable for the **current program object**

This means `glUseProgram` has to be done **before** `glUniformMatrix4fv`:

```
GLint locPrj = glGetUniformLocation( shader, "proj" );
GLint locView = glGetUniformLocation( shader, "view" );
GLint locModel = glGetUniformLocation( shader, "model" );

.....

glUseProgram(shader);

glUniformMatrix4fv(locPrj, 1, GL_FALSE, &proj[0][0]);
glUniformMatrix4fv(locView, 1, GL_FALSE, &view[0][0]);
glUniformMatrix4fv(locModel, 1, GL_FALSE, &model[0][0]);
```

To set up a identity matrix you should use `glm::mat4(1.0f);`

```
glm::mat4 model = glm::mat4(1.0f);
```

Further, I recommend to use [`glm::lookAt`](https://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.8/api/a00169.html), for setting up the view matrix. Try something like:

```
 glm::mat4 view = glm::lookAt( 
     glm::vec3( 2.0f, -5.0f, 2.0f ),
     glm::vec3( 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f ),
     glm::vec3( 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f ) );
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I also realized that I was setting my model matrix to nothing each time i initialized it on CPU by making model = glm::mat4() (which I changed to glm::mat4(1)) which lead to why nothing was being rendered on the GPU, through every iteration I tried of projection and ordering of my code with glUseProgram and such before I came to StackOverflow for assistance. Thank you for the help!